# no django package in pipfile (windows 10)

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, pip, pipenv

Hello i started my first Django project yesterday and after some tests i started a new "serious one" i created a new directory created a new virtual enviroement , installed django a created a new project, it works but on the pipfile i don't see Django.....

what i did in the new directory i created is:

```
pip install pipenv
pipenv shell
pip install Django==3.1
django-admin startproject secondtest .
python manage.py runserver
```

on the pipfile i had from the very first project i created i had django among the list of the packages

```
[[source]]
name = "pypi"
url = "https://pypi.org/simple"
verify_ssl = true

[dev-packages]

[packages]
django = "==3.1"

[requires]
python_version = "3.8"
```

while on the second one

```
[[source]]
name = "pypi"
url = "https://pypi.org/simple"
verify_ssl = true

[dev-packages]

[packages]

[requires]
python_version = "3.8"
```

i also did

```
pipenv install requests
```

and it adds it in the packages list....

could it be that i messed up something?

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, you're wondering why Django didn't appear in your packages. It's because you used `pip install django` instead of `pipenv install django`

Comment: yea but i used pip the first time too (copied and pasted from the Django's website...) i did the exact same steps....

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the issue. Are you just confused because `pip install` added it to the pipfile or what?

Comment: No my confusion is that when i open my pipfile after i installed django i should se [packages]
django = "==3.1" in the packages of my pipfile but i don't see it

Comment: again i did the same steps and used pip install the first time too

Comment: That's what I'm pointing out. You won't see it because you used `pip install django` instead of `pipenv install django`. In order for it to be added to your pipfile, you need to use `pipenv`

Comment: yea but why the very first time i installed it  on the first project it appeared ?i didn't used pipenv but pip install Django==3.1

Comment: It could have to do with the mapping. See: https://pipenv.pypa.io/en/latest/install/#virtualenv-mapping-caveat

Comment: hmm i see...and could this cause me some troubles later?